# Определить следующие 6 месяцев

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Как можно при помощи moment.js определить следующие 6 месяцев? Например, сегодня 12 месяц по счёту и я бы хотел на выходе получить массив:

`['12', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А без него можно?

```js
var m = 12
var res = []

for (var q=m; q<m+6; ++q) {
  res.push((q-1) % 12 + 1)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))

res = res.map(function addZero(x) {
  return (x < 10 ? "0" : "") + x
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

PS: Код можно порефакторить, я просто постарался написать его понятно.

Comment: Можно и без него :) Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

До меня внезапно дошло, как я мог бы сделать это с **moment.js**:

```js
let months = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for(let i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
  months[i] = moment().add(i, 'months').format('YYYY-MM');
  console.log(months[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А если сегодня 31 января?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну вроде бы нормально всё. https://jsfiddle.net/vbayhgag/

Comment: Да, действительно нормально: `2018-01-31
2018-02-28
2018-03-31
2018-04-30
2018-05-31
2018-06-30`, а я думал, он на первое число перейдёт, если нудного дня нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вот моё решение - одна строчка в цикле.

```js
var start = 10;
var plus = 6;
var rez = [];

for(var i=-1;i<plus;i++) {
   rez.push((start + i) % 12 + 1);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(rez));
```

Comment: Начальный месяц не попадает в диапазон, а так - да.

Comment: @ Qwertiy так в задаче выводит следующие месяцы, я так понял исключая текущий, но включить его можно просто итерируя с -1. Я думаю можно оценить труды друг-друга ))

Comment: @Qwertiy вы правы, почитал условие повнимательнее, исправил, теперь работает в соответсвии с условием